# Transitive closure in KodKod

Tags: alloy

I have a problem with using the method **closure()** for relations. If someone could explain how does the transitive closure work in KodKod.

Let's take for example:

```
Relation r1 = Relation.nary("r1",4);
Relation r2 = Relation.binary("r2");
Relation i = Relation.unary("i");
Relation j = Relation.unary("j");
Formula f = r.in(r2.product(i).product(j));
```

and I want to know how to say : a variable k Oneof(j) not in the transitive closure of the relation r1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arity of relation `r1` in your example is 4, and transitive closure can only be applied to binary relations.

Assuming `r1` is binary, something like `k.in(r1.closure()).not()`, where `k` is any expression that evaluates to a binary relation, should work.

Comment: yes I have already done that I had just some truble with making my relation binary by adding some joins but it worked so thank u anyway.